# How to change the background of a android Dialog Box

Tags: java, android, background, dialog, android-alertdialog

How can I change the background color programatically of a dialog box?

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.tnc)
        //.setTitle(R.string.tnc_title)
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                Log.d(TAG, "OK Button Clicked");

                dialog.dismiss();
                finish();

            }//end onClick
        });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
```

Comment: you must be create your own layout to change backgroud of dialog.otherwise you can set style and theme of alert dialog.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best way to do it !

Firstly make a dialog box programmatically .

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog1 = new Dialog(Page.this,R.style.myBackgroundStyle);
                Window window = dialog1.getWindow();

                window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
                window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable());
                dialog1.setTitle(null);
                dialog1.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


               dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);  

                dialog1.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                  new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
                dialog1.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                description.setText(DESCRIPTION);
                heading_name.setText(PRODUCT_NAME);

                Button abc = (Button)dialog1.findViewById(R.id.abc);
                  abc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                    }
                   });
                  Button xyz = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.xyz);
                  retailer_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                     dialog1.dismiss();
                    }
                   });
                dialog1.show();


            }
        });
```

and now create a new xml file and set this code in your xml (Dialog Layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/description_layout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top|right"
    android:gravity="right|top"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/desription_layout2"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dropdown_white_background"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/abc"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@drawable/curve_1"
            android:text="abc"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>


        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:background="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/xyz"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@drawable/curve_1"
            android:text="xyz"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and if you want to do additional stuff with your dialog such as rounding the corners of the dialog of the button then create a new xml in the drawable and the add this as the background accordingly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true">

        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <corners android:radius="3dip" />



            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#ffffff" />

            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:endColor="#ccffff" android:startColor="#ccffff" />

        </shape>

        </item>

    <item android:state_focused="true"><shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="3dip" />



            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#ffffff" />

            <solid android:color="#66ffff" />

        </shape>

        </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <corners android:radius="3dip" />



            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#66ffff" />

            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:endColor="#66ffff" android:startColor="#66ffff" />
        </shape>

        </item>

</selector>
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

In that case you require to make a custom dialog box.

Refer this tutorial here which illustrates that well.
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/659766/Android-Custom-DialogBox

Hop it helps.!!

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom layout and set it as the layout for your dialog box.

You can use this code:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_box);
```